# Is my server using SSL encryption to deliver e-mails?

Tags: python, ssl, sendmail, smtp

I have deployed a little mail server using `sendmail`. I think the agent is properly configured to accept delivery requests both with and without encryption. That's because, with the following telnet session:

```
usr@host:~$ nc -Cw 60 localhost 25
220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1; Tue, 8 Dec 2020 19:24:30 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
EHLO localhost
250-mail.mydomain.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
MAIL FROM: postmaster@mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 postmaster@mydomain.com... Sender ok
RCPT TO: myemail@hotmail.it
250 2.1.5 myemail@hotmail.it... Recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
From: postmaster@mydomain.com
To: myemail@hotmail.it
Subject: Sendmail test

This is a test mail delivered with Sendmail.
.
250 2.0.0 0B8JOUMo005314 Message accepted for delivery
QUIT
221 2.0.0 mail.mydomain.com closing connection
```

..and Python code snippets:

```
def send_mail_ssl(subject, text, receiver, sender):
  body = _BODY_PATTERN.format(sender=sender,
                              receiver=receiver,
                              subject=subject,
                              text=text)
  context = ssl.create_default_context()
  with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('mail.mydomain.com', 465, context=context) as server:
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, body)

def send_mail_tls(subject, text, receiver, sender):
  body = _BODY_PATTERN.format(sender=sender,
                              receiver=receiver,
                              subject=subject,
                              text=text)
  context = ssl.create_default_context()
  try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.mydomain.com', 25)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, body)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
  finally:
    server.quit()
```

...the e-mail delivery is successful. However, I am not sure that an encrypted session is established with the target SMTP node in order to deliver the e-mail. How could I check this?

**12/09 Update**
Since they have been mentioned in comments, I am going to add here also some headers included in my test e-mail:

```
Received: from AM6EUR05HT200.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2603:10a6:3:e3::27) by HE1PR06MB3930.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS
 via HE1PR0502CA0017.EURPRD05.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Tue, 8 Dec 2020 17:43:15 +0000
Received: from AM6EUR05FT016.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:e400:fc11::49) by
 AM6EUR05HT200.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com (2a01:111:e400:fc11::294)
 with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.3632.17; Tue, 8 Dec
 2020 17:43:14 +0000
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is MYSERVERIP)
 smtp.mailfrom=mail.mydomain.com; live.it; dkim=none (message not signed)
 header.d=none;live.it; dmarc=bestguesspass action=none
 header.from=mail.mydomain.com;compauth=pass reason=109
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of mail.mydomain.com
 designates MYSERVERIP as permitted sender)
 receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=MYSERVERIP;
 helo=mail.mydomain.com;
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (MYSERVERIP) by
 AM6EUR05FT016.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.233.240.243) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.3632.17 via Frontend Transport; Tue, 8 Dec 2020 17:43:14 +0000
X-IncomingTopHeaderMarker:
 OriginalChecksum:A8C3955649979800BCCE5770882A4FE8994D8B0B90393756BB8AD24255EBB904;UpperCasedChecksum:DC234C8D58F32E07B6AFB42D6ABE9D17CF745F6968D869D01974CBC93315655A;SizeAsReceived:484;Count:6
Received: from mail.mydomain.com (mail.mydomain.com [MYSERVERIP])
    by mail.mydomain.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTPS id 0B8HhDPU003097
    (version=TLSv1.3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256 verify=NOT)
    for <myemail@hotmail.it>; Tue, 8 Dec 2020 17:43:14 GMT
[...]
```

Comment: Check the mail headers for `smtp`/`esmtp`

Comment: @Panki, which header let me discriminate an encrypted transmission from an in-clear one? Anyway, I am going to update the question adding part of my test e-mail headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first try - with the telnet session is using classic connection to SMTP port tcp/25. That's all right and standard. You can use it and after EHLO you can switch to an encrypted session with STARTTLS. But your Python is configured to use SMTP over SSL so called SMTPS, tried some time ago and later mostly abandoned. It uses tcp/465 and is encrypted since the beggining. Has some drawbacks.
2. So yes, your Python uses a kind of encryption when sending e-mail to your submission server. But it doesn't have anything to do with the transmission of an e-mail from your submission server to the final destination server (directly or with another relay(s)). It's negotiated by the servers involved and their list of algorithms, setup preference and so on. AFAIK there is no standard forcing encryption between SMTP MTAs.

Comment: Does this mean that if I want to send an e-mail to my Hotmail account, for instance, there is no warranty that my SMTP node establishes an encrypted connection with Outlook SMTP nodes, even if the delivery routine starts with an encryption method (SSL or TLS)? Do you confirm that?
If yes, is it possible to instruct your SMTP to send e-mails only to nodes that accept SSL or TLS encryption?

Comment: There is a "daemon of backward compatibility" there. You shouldn't force encryption for e-mail communication on wide Internet as this breaks RFCs (=compatibility with some other MTAs). And yes, it might be possible to have TLS startup and use "dummy" ciphers. But in this case, I don't see any reason not to force encryption at least on MTAs, you have possibility to influence. E. g. I use following on my servers: `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous`